# Move To Element via Actions with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, web-testing

I'm trying to click on the element on the main page from site demoQA, but I'm facing issue that google ads block my click.
I've already tried to
`moveToElement()` from Actions class and with

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

but it didn't help.
How can I locate element to execute the test without hardcode?

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/");
}

@Test
public void navigateTest() {
    By framesLink = By.xpath("(//h5[text()='Alerts, Frame & Windows'])[1]");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(framesLink), 0, 0);
    driver.findElement(framesLink).click();
} 

//element click intercepted:
```

[image]

Comment: you could either close the ad, or scroll a bit more (as long as the ad doesn't follow the element). It may be easier to just close the ad if the exception appears when clicking and then click your original element again. (no need for actions or scrolling... the click() method already scrolls the element into view)  You could also just run a click using javascript, but not a great test case since a user wouldn't do that.

Comment: Ty, I've decided to zoom out